# lexical-binding not being enabled when evaluating .emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, lexical-scope

Here are some excerpts from my `.emacs`:

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
;; .emacs

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(diff-switches "-u")
 '(tab-always-indent (quote complete)))

;...    

(require 'dired)

;...    

(dotimes (i 12) (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd (concat "<f" (number-to-string (1+ i)) ">"))
          (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (forward-line (+ 4 i)))))
```

This should bind keys `f1` to `f12` in `dired-mode` to commands that jump to particular files in the list of files (ignoring `.` and `..`). However, initially, after starting emacs, these keys don't work - I get an error message `forward-line: Symbol's value as variable is void: i`. However, when I go to the top line of my `.emacs` and press C-x C-e to evaluate that line, and then go to the last line quoted above and press C-x C-e to evaluate that `dotimes` expression, those function keys start working!

Why is that?

By the way, it also doesn't work if I evaluate the whole buffer.

Comment: The `(setq lexical-binding t)` above changes the value of `lexical-binding` in the buffer that happens to be current when your `~/.emacs` is read, which is most likely `*scratch*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it is necessary to replace

```
(setq lexical-binding t)
```

with

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

The manual hints suggestively at this, but does not actually say so outright.

Comment: Consider filing a doc bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: The general rule is: never ever do `(setq lexical-binding t)` because it probably doesn't do what you think.